# Unifying quantum mechanics and general relativity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, unified-theories

I am very new to physics and I want to pursue Unified Field theory now when I read about how to unify quantum mechanics with relativity as they are essentially the same thing and a relation must be found I read that this can be done by unifying to he forces now I have not studied the math so if someone could explain to me why is this necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52211/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Why it’s necessary to study the math? Or why it’s necessary to unify QM and GR?