# Could space itself be made out of particles?

Tags: particle-physics, spacetime

Are there any theories out there that discuss the idea that space itself could be made out of particles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does String theory say that spacetime is not fundamental but should be considered an emergent phenomenon?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33428/)

Comment: Also related: [How does classical GR concept of space-time emerge from string theory?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1073/)

Comment: I've suggested a question that I think goes some way to duplicating your question. As it stands your question is too broad to be usefully answered here. You might want to Google *emergent spacetime* or something similar to see what sorts of approaches have been suggested, though this is a speculative area with no well established theories. However I think it's safe to say that there are no (plausible) suggestions that spacetime is *made out of particles* in any literal sense.

Comment: This question hasn't anything to do with the String theory. For example, answers about Diracs' sea of electrons were also acceptable here, but not in the "duplicate". This question was closed unfairly. You get a +1 as a protest against the phenomenon.